# Tagging strings in Java

Tags: java

How can i tag an array of string in java ?

I want to make an array of strings and tag them like :

```
m funny
s funny 
t boring
k boring
```

Then if the user can search for them by tagging like

```
search : funny
::
m,s
```

Comment: i suppose you want to use a [map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for mapping values

Comment: why not use `hashmap` where `keys` are tags and `values` are object for that tag. Or you may use `List of objects` as values,` if same tag has more than one values.

Comment: by the way, try to formulate your question clearer the next time - what is the context of your question and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using a [Guava MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) of tags to strings.  This way you can get all the Strings with a given tag with a single lookup.

```
MultiMap<String, String> tagStringMap = new MultiMap<String, String>();

// load up the tag to strings.
tagStringMap.put(tag1, string1);

// single lookup gets everything.
Collection<String> strings = tagStringMap.get(tag);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// key is tag, value all the strings which have this tag.
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> tags = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
// words that with the tag: funny
Set<String> words = tags.get("funny");
```

---

If one word can have multiple tags, then you might have another map:

```
// key is string, value all the tags for the string
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> invertedTags = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
// tags of the word: "m"
Set<String> tags = invertedTags.get("m");
```

Answer (score 2):

**Create `HashMap`s to store the forward and reverse mappings.**

```
HashMap<String,String> stringTags;
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> tagStrings;
```

Then you can add the mapping like this:

```
public void tagString(String string, String tag) {
  this.stringTags.put(string, tag);
  ArrayList<String> strings = this.tagStrings.get(tag);
  if (strings == null) {
    strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.tagStrings.put(tag, strings);
  }
  strings.add(string);
}
```

Then you can access like this:

```
private String getTag(String string) {
  return this.stringTags.get(string);
}

private String[] getStrings(String tag) {
  ArrayList<String> strings = this.tagStrings.get(tag);
  if (strings == null)
    return new String[0];
  return strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
}
```

Remember to synchronize these functions if this data will be accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: i am new at Java .. and i can't begin a code ... my mind is messed up ..  for tagging program. i have thought about making two arrays of strings and connect them together, when user search will search by the tag that have the ID of the other word in the 2nd string, how can i make this ?!
-searching,adding and removing tags 
please.. :/
using simple codes i can't understand the hash mapping or using it ...

Comment: @MonDo021 You need to start going through the tutorials on the Java website until you "get it."  There's way to program that doesn't involve you learning the fundamentals.

Comment: I learned this all in a class called "Data Structures".  Lots of comments for not a single up-vote.  Is this really that un-helpful?

Comment: +1, I have no idea no why nobody upvote, even you brought this to meta.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestTaggedStrings {

   Map<String, String> taggedStrings = new HashMap<String, String>();

   public TestTaggedStrings() {
      taggedStrings.put("m", "funny");
      taggedStrings.put("s", "funny");
      taggedStrings.put("t", "boring");
      taggedStrings.put("k", "boring");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestTaggedStrings testStrings = new TestTaggedStrings();
      System.out.println(testStrings.search("funny"));
   }

   public List<String> search(String searchTerm) {
      List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
      Set<String> keys = taggedStrings.keySet();
      for(String key : keys) {
         if(searchTerm.equals(taggedStrings.get(key))) {
            matches.add(key);
         }
      }
      return matches;
   }
}
```

Test:

```
$>javac TestTaggedStrings.java
$>java TestTaggedStrings
[s, m]
```

Comment: This algorithm is very slow when the list of mappings gets large.

Comment: @Erick, It is surprising fast even for 1 million entries, but certainly not optimal. On my machine it took 39 ms to search one million entries. Obviously a MultiMap would be a faction of a micro-second. ;)

Comment: @Jonathon this is a very bad solution. Why not map from the tag to the list of words? See the answer by @james-xu. That is better in terms of both time and space complexity!

Comment: mmm thank u all for trying helping me .... but i can't under stand most of ur answers because .... i am just new programmer :D

Comment: i will post the whole question to u

Comment: @Elad No argument that there are more elegant solutions (including @James.Xu's), but time and space are both debatable.  Strings may be interned leading to little or no space savings from his answer.  I doubt time requirements matter to the question asker.  Question asker didn't know how he could apply a `Map` to his problem and that's all I hoped to show.

Comment: @Deepak You can now copy/paste into a file called TestTaggedStrings.java and try it.